# Making an Ember Computed Property depend on a Variable

Tags: ember.js

Suppose I have a computed property on a view:

```
TestView=Ember.View.extend({
  computedProperty:function(){
    return this.get("elementId")+"test"
  }.property("targetObject.{{elementId goes here}}")
})
```

I want to make the property depend on the model property with the attribute name equivalent to the id on that view element.  However, I haven't found an elegant way to do this.  I need to do this to make my code as general as possible.  My solution so far is to make the property dependent on targetObject's id and then call object.notifyPropertyChange(id) whenever I need binding to update.

To add some clarity.  Suppose I have a view that displays a number that is bound to a property on the model.  However, I want the number to be formatted with commas when it is displayed.  I could easily write a computed property for each possible attribute that will do the formatting.  Instead though, I just want a generic view that will know to take the value of the attribute of the model with the same name as the view's elementId property.  Here is an example of my hacky solution:

```
TestView=Ember.View.extend({
  computedProperty:function(){
  var id=this.get("elementId")
    return addCommas(this.get("targetObject").get(id))
  }.property("id")
})
```

I then call:
    object.notifyPropertyChange(id) whenever one of the attributes on the model changes.  It works and achieves my goals but I was looking for a more elegant solution.

In the view the formatted value is displayed in an custom textfield.

```
{{view App.CustomTextField value=computedProperty id="someAttribute}}
```

Comment: Could you provide more context? I'm unsure of what you're trying to achieve. The id's of the view won't change after they are a rendered. The properties defined within the view are already encapsulated within it's instance.

Comment: You may need to manually add an observer on the view init. http://emberjs.com/api/#method_addObserver

Comment: I have view elements that have as their ids the attribute names of a model.  I want a property on each view to depend on the attribute with the same name as that view's id but I don't want to explicitly name the property in .property(attribute name goes here).  Instead I want to set it programmatically.

Comment: I'm still a little confused about what you're asking. I made this fiddle, http://emberjs.jsbin.com/zukifoya/3/edit ,  It updates a property on the view whenever a property with the same name of an id is changed. Without explicitly defining the property name in the view. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: That is kind of what I wanted.  The problem with that solution is that it is no better than defining a computed property that depends on the attribute.  What I want is one generic computed property that knows to update based on the property with the same name as that view's id.  That way I don't have to have hundreds of computed properties on the view, one for each possible value of the attribute.  In other words, this is a view that I will be using across multiple models with multiple properties but will have the same functionality for each(except for the dependent property).

Answer (score 0):

Just use a helper which formats numbers with commas. You don't need any properties, computed or otherwise.

**test.hbs**

```
Hello, I am a formatted {{add-commas number}}.
```

**helpers/add-commas.js**

```
Ember.Handlebars.helper('add-commas', function(value) {
  return value.toLocaleString();
});
```

Comment: My concern is that I am displaying this value in a textField and the value is being bound to the textField's value property.  Can you bind a view's attribute to a helper output?